# CRM Online 2015 Update 1 charts show all data from the underlying views until the charts are manually refreshed

Tags: dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-online, dynamics-crm-2015

In CRM Online 2015 Update 1 instances I experience charts on forms not showing the correct data until they are manually refreshed.

Charts in general show all data from the underlying view when the form is loaded. Only after manually refreshing a certain chart does it show "Only Related Records".
As an example, I have added a chart to the Account entity as seen below. Both the chart and the shown subgrid are using the same view. Even though there is only 1 related record the chart shows all data from "My Open Opportunities" after form load:
[image: Chart before clicking the refresh button]

After refreshing the chart by clicking the small recycle-icon the correct data related to the current record (in this case 1) is shown:
[image: Chart after clicking the refresh button]

I have tested this in 3 different CRM Online 2015 Update 1 instances which all exhibit the same behavior. Additionally, this is seen for both system and custom entities. 
A similar chart setup in CRM Online 2015 without Update 1 works as expected.

Comment: What kind of attribute types are you using for the chart?

Comment: Any. It is reproducible with system charts and custom charts, not just with the specific example above.

Comment: I got a client with update 1 on online 2015 as well. Give me a minute to review.

Comment: I reviewed charts on different system entities. All work as expected for two of our customers. I would recommend creating a support ticket.

Comment: Thanks for trying to reproduce. It is valuable to know that it works as expected for you. I will create a support ticket and update with an answer when I have a solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue is supposed to be fixed in [*Service Update 1 for Microsoft Dynamics CRM Online 7.1.1*](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/3104429). From the changelog: "*Charts within a subgrid are displaying all records when they should actually display only related records.*".

The expected release date is around the middle of December.

Answer (score 0):

I've got the same problem.

Microsoft has changed how they load forms. For now, you can switch back to the old way by going to Settings -> Administration -> System Settings -> General tab, and selecting Yes for “Use legacy form rendering”

This is only a temporary measure as that option is likely to be removed, but maybe Microsoft will support charts in forms or whatever the issue is by then.

PS:
Drawback is that the new way of loading forms is much faster, so you'll lose som e time if you switch back.
I Haven't tested this yet, but maybe you could add some javascript on the onLoad event to automatically select the view, like your users have to do now manually:

```
Xrm.Page.getControl(subgridname).getViewSelector().setCurrentView(viewname);
```

but this isn't pretty either

Comment: Good idea in regards to changing to legacy form rendering. Unfortunately charts still behave in the same way for me, even with legacy form rendering.